# How to get a single record from a related table in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have this model (simplified version):

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='photos')
    photographer = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Genre(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Decade(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    decade = models.ForeignKey(Decade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

As you can see *some* albums have photos. What I want to do is show a list with all genres, which will show how many albums there are in that genre for a particular decade, plus a photo for that genre. The photo should be the photo from an album in that genre. I can't get the first record's photo because it may not have a photo, so it should get the photo of an album that has a photo.

Example:

Genres:

```
1 | Rock
2 | Punk
3 | Jazz
```

Albums:

```
1 | Rock All   | genre = rock | decade = sixties
2 | Rock It Up | genre = rock | decade = sixties
3 | Jazz Basiq | genre = jazz | decade = nineties
4 | Jazz Uno   | genre = jazz | decade = sixties
5 | Punkio     | genre = punk | decade = sixties
```

Photos:

```
1 | rockitup.jpg   | Belongs to Album 2
2 | uno.jpg        | Belongs to Album 4
3 | punkio.jpg     | Belongs to Album 5
4 | punkio2.jpg    | Belongs to Album 5
5 | punkio3.jpg    | Belongs to Album 5
6 | basiq.jpg      | Belongs to Album 3
```

So, what I want to ultimately show in my template is something like:

```
In the sixties this was happening:

{% for genre in genres %}
  <li>Genre: {{ genre.title }} has {{ genre.total }} albums and here is an image: 
    <img src="{{ genre.image.url }}"></li>
{% endfor %}
```

In my view this is what I do:

```
genres = Genre.objects.annotate(total=Count('albums', filter=Q(decade__name='sixties')))
```

That works well - I am successfully retrieving the total number of albums for the decade I am wanting to show. Now the question is how to I also show the right image? In SQL I would consider a subquery:

```
... (SELECT photo.image FROM album a JOIN photo ON album.photo = photo.id WHERE a.genre = genre.id AND photo.id IS NOT NULL) AS image ...
```

Something like that. But I'm not sure what the right way is to do this in Django. Do I somehow annotate it with a single record? Do I use a custom template filter (and if so, how should this work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this using [backward related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects):

```
{% for genre in genres %}
  <li>Genre: {{ genre.title }} has {{ genre.total }} albums and here are an image: 
    <img src="{{ genre.album_set.all.0.photo.url }}"></li>
{% endfor %}
```

It will get first album's image of the genre. You can get all the images of genre by:

```
{% for genre in genres %}
  <li>Genre: {{ genre.title }} has {{ genre.total }} albums and here is all images: 
    {% for album in genre.album_set.all %}
        <img src="{{ album.photo.url }}"></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Or**

Create a property method inside Genre Model and show it in template. Like:

```
#model
class Genre(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_image(self):
      album = self.album_set.all().first()
      if album:
         return album.photo

# template
{% for genre in genres %}
  <li>Genre: {{ genre.title }} has {{ genre.total }} albums and here is an image: 
    {{ genre.get_image.photo.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

### Update: using subquery

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery


albums_subquery = Album.objects.filter(genre=OuterRef('pk'))
Genre.objects.annotate(image=Subquery(albums_subquery.values('photo')[:1]))

# and then you can keep the template implementation as it is as described in question.
```

[Subquery documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).

Comment: Thanks but the problem is I want to only get one image, which must be of an album in that genre AND from the particular decade that I am looking at. So basically I want to run a number of queries on that subset, somehow...

Comment: Thanks for this. I will look at the subqueries. However, in the examples the "decade" filter is not taken into account. Basically I have need to query a subset of all albums (WHERE decade = 'sixties') instead of just listing _all_ albums, and then get the first record that does have an image (AND photo IS NOT NULL). See my original question.

Comment: You can annotate both. I just made a simplified example. You can do `Queryset.annotate(..).annotate(..)` or `annotate(count=..., image=...)`

Comment: OK great! I am going to investigate this, it sounds promising.